# Is there a simple way to target each of these h2 with there corresponding img hover jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have Six Images and on hover they fade out a static quote and replace it with the images quote.

The Quotes are located in a row below all of the images.

Is there a simple way to target img to quote? This is what I have so far

```
     div class="top-icons">
  <div class="span2 first">
    <a href="http://19610.hs-sites.com/inbound-marketing">
        <img src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/19610/file-511184919-png/img/inbound-icon.png?t=1392133012000" alt="Inbound Marketing" />
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="span2 2nd">
    <a href="http://19610.hs-sites.com/web-design-optimization">
        <img src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/19610/file-511189334-png/img/webdesign-icon.png?t=1392133011000" alt="Web Site Design and Development" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="span2 3rd">
    <a href="http://19610.hs-sites.com/search-engine-optimization">
        <img src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/19610/file-517790482-png/img/seo-icon.png?t=1392133014000" alt="Search Engine Optimization" />
    </a>
  </div>

</div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="quotes">
        <h2 class="main">Quote Affiated with Each Image</h2>
        <h2 class="one">Inbound Marketing</h2>
        <h2 class="two">Web Design and Development</h2>
    </div>
```

Jquery There has to be a simpler and more efficient way I am also getting duplicate text on hovers.

```
$('.first').hover(
    function() {
        $('.quotes').find('.main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('.quotes').find('.one').fadeIn('slow');
        })
    },
    function() {
        $('.quotes').find('.one').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('.quotes').find('.main').fadeIn('slow');
        })
    }
);

$('.2nd').hover(
    function() {
        $('.quotes').find('.main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('.quotes').find('.two').fadeIn('slow');
        })
    },
    function() {
        $('.quotes').find('.two').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('.quotes').find('.main').fadeIn('slow');
        })
    }
);

$('.3rd').hover(
    function() {
        $('.quotes').find('.main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('.quotes').find('.three').fadeIn('slow');
        })
    },
    function() {
        $('.quotes').find('.one').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('.quotes').find('.three').fadeIn('slow');
        })
    }
);
```

Fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/KzZQU/13/

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that will work for your current HTML.

Javascript:

```
$('.span2').hover(function() {
    var i = $('.span2').index(this),
        quote = $('.quotes h2').not('.main').get(i);

    $('.main').hide();
    $(quote).stop().fadeIn();     
}, function() {
    $('.quotes h2').hide();
    $('.main').stop().fadeIn();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/95Zkw/

Although having a custom attribute as others have suggested is a tidier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom attribute on your main divs to specify the class of the quote you want to show:

```
<div class="top-icons">
  <div class="span2 first" quote="one">
  <a href="http://19610.hs-sites.com/inbound-marketing">
    <img src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/19610/file-511184919-png/img/inbound-icon.png?t=1392133012000" alt="Inbound Marketing" />
  </a>
</div>
<div class="span2 2nd" quote="two">
<a href="http://19610.hs-sites.com/web-design-optimization">
    <img src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/19610/file-511189334-png/img/webdesign-icon.png?t=1392133011000" alt="Web Site Design and Development" />
</a>
</div>
<div class="span2 3rd" quote="three">
<a href="http://19610.hs-sites.com/search-engine-optimization">
    <img src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/19610/file-517790482-png/img/seo-icon.png?t=1392133014000" alt="Search Engine Optimization" />
</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Then you only need one simple javascript call:

```
$('.span2').hover(
function() {
    var quote = $(this).attr("quote");
    $('.quotes').find('.main').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.quotes').find("."+quote).fadeIn('slow');
    })
},
function() {
    var quote = $(this).attr("quote");
    $('.quotes').find('.'+quote).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('.quotes').find('.main').fadeIn('slow');
    })
}
);
```

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KzZQU/13/

Comment: Do you mind updating this fiddle i am unable to get this solution to work.

Answer (score 0):

put quote texts inside of the markup of your images (in `alt` attribute or `data-anyname` attribute):

```
<img class="show-quote-on-hover" src="http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/19610/file-511184919-png/img/inbound-icon.png?t=1392133012000" alt="Inbound Marketing" data-quote="Inbound Marketing"/>
<div id="quotes"></div>
```

write as many images as you need... leave `<div id="quotes">` empty as it is.
then write some jquery like this:

```
$('.show-quote-on-hover').on('mouseenter',function(){
  var quote = $('<div style="display:none;">' + $(this).data('quote') + '</div>');
  $('#quotes').prepend(quote);
  quote.show(1000);
});
```

in this example your quote-text will be taken from `data-quote` attribute. To extract it from `alt` attribute `$(this).attr('alt')` should be used.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3U83/2/
feel free to change `show` and `hide` to `fadeIn` `fadeOut` ...have fun!

...but if you don't like this "history-feed-effect" just use `empty()`
 http://jsfiddle.net/y3U83/3/